# Ввести x, вычислить и вывести y

Tags: c++

Задание

> Ввести x, вычислить и вывести y = 11 
> *x^10 + 10 * x^9 + 9 * x^8 + ... + 2* 
> x + 1;

Простое подставление функции y = 11 * x^10 + 10 * x^9 + 9 * x^8 + ... + 2 * x + 1 неприемлимо.

Написал прогу

**UPD: переписал прогу, используя FOR и POW.**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double x;
    double y = 0;
    cout << "Enter x = ";
    cin  >> x;
    for (double n = 11.0; n <= 1.0 ;  n--)
    {
        y = y + n * pow (x, n--);
    }

    cout << "Answer = " << y << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

При её выполнение, после ввода X, ничего не происходит =\

**UPD: теперь выдаёт ответ, где y=0. Не могу найти проблему.**

Comment: Присмотритесь к строке
    while (n = 1)

UPD
И, мне кажется, оператор ^ в C++ и в вашем представлении работают по разному :)

Comment: т.е. лучше использовать pow(a;b) и #include <cmath>?

Comment: for ... n = 11.0 ... n <= 1.0

вас ничего не смущает?

Comment: POW работает только с числами double.

Comment: http://hscripts.com/tutorials/cpp/type-casting.php добро пожаловать в мир логичного программирования

Comment: @Алексей Кофанов, сравнение чисел с плавающей запятой - та ещё развлекуха, что на равенство, что на больше/меньше. Сейчас этой темы касаться смысла нет, но как счётчик итерации в 99.99% случаев стоит использовать целые. Даже если шаг итерации - дробный :)

Comment: Не нужны в этой задаче никакие *pow()*!!!

Просто цикл, в котором на каждом шаге вычисляете (суммируйте с "хвоста" формулы).

    double sum, x, xx;
    int  n;
    ...
    cin >> x;
    ...
    for (n = ...; ...; n++) {
      xx *= x; sum += xx * n;
    }

Ну, а начальные значения `n`, `xx` и `sum` сделайте самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n <= 1.0 заменить на n >= 1.0
pow (x, n--) заменить на pow (x, n-1)

Comment: как же я затупил :D моя благодарность.

Answer (score 3):

```
double r = 0.0;
for(double k = 11.0; k >=1.0; k--)
  r += r * x + k;
return r;
```

Answer (score 2):

у вас в строке while(n=1), идёт не сравнение n и 1, а их присваивание

Comment: Уже исправил, новая проблема.

Comment: Странно, что Ваш преподаватель заставляет вычислять функцию этим диковатым методом. Вообще говоря, такие задачи с полиномами решаются с помощью схемы Горнера, в которой нет необходимости применять pow(). Эта схема минимизирует количество действий умножения при вычислении результата. Поскольку коэффициенты полинома зависят от степени  x, задача еще более упрощается.

Comment: @BuilderC тем более, что далеко не каждый компилятор оптимизирует pow для целых показателей степени.